# Is it possible to blow-up in codimension one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup

In the context of complex manifolds, one can consider a blow-up along a complex submanifold. For a linear subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ there is a general procedure to perform such a blow-up: for a subspace $\mathbb{C}^m$ determined by the equations
$$
z_1 = z_2 = \ldots = z_{n-m} = 0 \,,
$$
we can introduce a projective space $\mathbb{CP}^{n-m-1}$ with coordinates $y_i$, and define the blown-up space $\tilde{X}$ by
$$
\tilde{X} = \{(z,y)~|~z_i y_j = z_j y_i \,, ~i,j=1,\ldots,n-m\} \subset \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{CP}^{n-m-1} \,,
$$
with a blow-down map that simply projects onto the $\mathbb{C}^n$ factor. The equations ensure that the blow-down is an isomorphism away from the original subspace, and sends a $\mathbb{CP}^{n-m-1}$ to a point everywhere on the subspace.

For codimension $n-m=1$, the above procedure doesn't define a blow-up, since $\mathbb{CP}^{n-m-1}$ is just a point. My question is: **Is there any similar construction for codimension one subspaces?**

Comment: Blow up is specifically designed to convert a subscheme to a Cartier divisor. So, if you have  a codimension one subscheme which is not a Cartier divisor, you can blow up and get something new. Blowing up Cartier divisor can not yield anything new.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for your helpful comment. Can there be a more interesting answer if I only ask for a smooth complex manifold that has a projection map which fails to be an isomorphism over a codimension one locus of the complex base?

Comment: This can not happen unless your base is so bad that the codimension one variety is not Cartier. I would recommend that you at least study what happens when you blow up a singular point of a curve.